# Appending a node to an array of pointer

Tags: c, list, nodes

I'm currently studying data structure using C, and now assigned to create an list using pointer. Then I got a problem when trying to add a element into my created list. This is my code right now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE
{
    int x;
    char c;
    struct NODE *next;
};
void make_list(struct NODE **n)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
    {
        *n = (struct NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
        (*n)->x = k+1;
        (*n)->c = 'A'+k;
        n = &(*n)->next;
    }
    *n = NULL;
}

void print_list(struct NODE *node)
{
    int k = 0;
    printf("###### Content of list ######\n");

    while(node != NULL)
    {
        printf("[%d]:x = %d, c = %c\n", k++, node->x, node->c);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void append_last_node(struct NODE *node)
{
    struct NODE *next;

    while(node->next != NULL)
    {
        node->next = next;
    }

    node->next = (struct NODE *)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));

    node->next->next = NULL;
    node->next->x = 100;
    node->next->c = 'a';
}

int main()
{
    struct NODE *n;

    make_list(&n);
    print_list(n);

    append_last_node(n);
    print_list(n);

    return 0;
```

Once I run this one, only the list that I had created in make_list function was printed while the append_last_node function was not printed and the process of execution does not automatically end after my list was printed.

```
###### Content of list ###### 
[0]:x = 1, c = A 
[1]:x = 2, c = B 
[2]:x = 3, c = C 
[3]:x = 4, c = D 
[4]:x = 5, c = E 
[5]:x = 6, c = F 
[6]:x = 7, c = G 
[7]:x = 8, c = H 
[8]:x = 9, c = I 
[9]:x = 10, c = J 
[10]:x = 11, c = K 
[11]:x = 12, c = L 
[12]:x = 13, c = M 
[13]:x = 14, c = N
[14]:x = 15, c = O 
[15]:x = 16, c = P 
[16]:x = 17, c = Q 
[17]:x = 18, c = R 
[18]:x = 19, c = S 
[19]:x = 20, c = T
```

Is there any mistake in my append_last_node function or are there something that I am missing right there?

P/S: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you program in C then please use only the C tag. C and C++, even though they share some syntax, are otherwise two *very* different languages.

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". Use a real language.

Comment: there is no language called C/C++. The code you have looks like C

Comment: ...there should be a disclaimer for every question that tags C and C++, that would save us a lot of comments. And imho question containing the phrase C/C++ could be banned completely ;)

Comment: And nowhere in your code do you have an *array*. What you have is a pretty standard implementation of a single-linked list.

Comment: @user463035818 Or you can create a new language called "C/C++", just to prank people who use the term.

Comment: Lastly about your problems, I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Even some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should make the problem in your append function quite clear.

Comment: Yeah... I looked for the expected realloc() where you make the pointer array longer so you can add new elements, but did not find it?   I don't see much correlation between your requirement and code?

Comment: @NickyC nice idea. It would be a true superset of C and C++ syntax-wise and consist of only undefined behaviour (would make it rather easy to write a standard and be just natural as `c/c++` is ub in both languages afaik). Joking aside, its a pity that this term is used so often and we cannot blame someone who doesnt know better....

Comment: `*n = NULL;` doesn't make any sense. This causes your function to always return NULL.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm student who is very new to programming, and my lecturer use g++ while compiling his program. So I thought that he is using C++. Learned something new here. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: If you compile this as C++, it **is** C++! **Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics** Try removing the (in C) unnecessary and deprecated casts of `void *` on `malloc`. And if that's supposed to be a C course, get better lecturer, he doesn't know at least one of the language well enough to teach it. You wouldn't compile Java code with a Brainfuck compiler either.

Comment: @NickyC: I once proposed to create a `c/c++` tag and automatically putting all tagged questions to hold and into a queue for clearance.

Comment: @Olaf it is rare, but there are questions where both tags are relevant and putting those on hold would be a bit unfair imho

Comment: @user463035818: Hence the clearance queue! They are in fact very rare, so it would not be much of a loss. Most double-tagged are about how to call C functions from C++, which is a C++ vs. C ABI (`extern "C") matter, not about the C language. We could take badged into account for the decission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze this code:

> ```
> struct NODE *next;
>
> while(node->next != NULL)
> {
>     node->next = next;
> }
> ```

First a pointer to `NODE` is declared, `next`, and never initialized. It points to a random location of memory. In general, better initialize everything.

`node`, passed as parameter, is the head of the list.

At the first iteration, `node->next` is the second element of the list, clearly not null since the list should have 20 elements.

To this element, you do assign `next`, which is uninitialized.

**Undefined behaviour** follows.

At this point `node->next` is some random address, which could even be inaccessible by your process. **The last node will be appended to this random memory location** or crash.

What you were after, is looping till the last element of the list. Therefore:

```
struct NODE *curr = node;

while(curr->next != NULL)
{
    curr= curr->next;
}
```

So `curr` will be the last node.

Comment: @ downvoter: please comment. I am open to amendments and constructive criticism.